# Multiple template reference for same element using @viewchild in angular2

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

As shown below can I refer multiple local variables to the same element? `#datatable #selectionTable`

Basically, The issue Im facing is that, Im able to access my child component `DatatableComponent` using `@viewChild`.

But I'm not able to access another child component by importing with `@viewChild`. when I try to console and see my newly imported component Im getting `DatatableComponent`'s details only instead of `DataTableSelectionComponent` details.

```
import { DataTableSelectionComponent } from '@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/components/body/selection.component';
import { DatatableComponent } from '@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/components/datatable.component';


@ViewChild('selectionTable') selectionComponent: DataTableSelectionComponent;
@ViewChild('datatable') datatableComponent: DatatableComponent;

<ngx-datatable #datatable #selectionTable class="striped" 
   [ngStyle]="_datatableHeight" [headerHeight]="datatableHeaderHeight"
   [selectionType]="'checkbox'" [rows]="_rows" [columns]="_columns" 
   [rowHeight]="rowHeight" [cssClasses]="cssClasses"
   [columnMode]="columnMode" (select)="onSelect($event)" 
   (activate)="activateRow($event)" [trackByProp]="'name'"
   [scrollbarV]="isScroll">

  <ngx-datatable-row-detail *ngIf='detailRow && detailRow.template' 
     [rowHeight]="detailRow.height" [template]="detailRow.template">
  </ngx-datatable-row-detail>

</ngx-datatable>
```

Comment: precisely please.

Comment: Updated the question with more details.

Comment: In your case selectionComponent and datatableComponent refer to same element, which is ngx-datatable. Why do you expect selectionTable to be DataTableSelectionComponent? It's unclear what the exact problem is.

Comment: it's not in the `view` of template, pass by content even I can't found your component in your `ngx` .

Comment: @estus actually, I need to trigger select event to the first row of the ngx data table when keyboard down key is pressed. For which I need to use component `selectionComponent` on the same ngx-datatable element itself.

Comment: An element corresponds to *one* component. I don't use this package, but looks like <ngx-datatable> corresponds to DatatableComponent.<ngx-datatable> won't be DataTableSelectionComponent under no circumstances. In order to have an instance of DataTableSelectionComponent  there should be [<datatable-selection> element](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/blob/master/src/components/body/selection.component.ts#L16). I'm still not sure what you're trying to achieve, but things don't work as you expect.

Comment: ok, Thanks for the details.

Comment: why you want to use two child name for the same component??